# Brute Force Number of pairs

Tags: javascript, data-structures, time-complexity

```
function noOfPairs(X,Y) {
   var ans = {};
   var arr = [];
   var count = 0;
   for(var i = 0;i< X.length; i++) {       
        for(var j=0;j < Y.length; j++) {
             if(Math.pow(X[i],Y[j]) > Math.pow(Y[j],X[i])) {
                count++;
             }
        }
    }
   console.log("Total number of pairs is   "+count);
}

var X= [2, 1, 6];
var Y =[1,5];
noOfPairs(X,Y);
```

I am trying to Find number of pairs (x, y) in an array such that x^y > y^x.It gives me correct result 3 but here time complexity is O(mn).Is there any way to optimize it

Comment: You might want to ask this on [codereview.se], but do read their guidelines for on-topic questions.

Comment: Try rearranging y^x into the form z^y so you can compare x to z.

Comment: The answer might depend on whether or not the numbers are always positive integers

Comment: Is this for a homework? Hint: There exists an `O(nlogn + mlogn)` solution, assuming only non negative integers.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a solution in **O(nLogn + mLogn)** time.

Here is the algorithm:

- Sort array Y[].
- For every x in X[], find the index idx of smallest number greater
  than x (also called ceil of x) in Y[] using binary search.
- All the numbers after idx satisfy the relation so just add (n-idx) to
  the count.

These will be the base cases for your program:

- If x = 0, then the count of pairs for this x is 0.
- If x = 1, then the count of pairs for this x is equal to count of 0s
  in Y[].

The following cases must be handled separately as they don’t follow the general rule that x smaller than y means x^y is greater than y^x.

- x = 2, y = 3 or 4
- x = 3, y = 2

I don't know Javascript, so here is the code in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

// This function return count of pairs with x as one element
// of the pair. It mainly looks for all values in Y[] where
// x ^ Y[i] > Y[i] ^ x
int count(int x, int Y[], int n, int NoOfY[])
{
    // If x is 0, then there cannot be any value in Y such that
    // x^Y[i] > Y[i]^x
    if (x == 0) return 0;

    // If x is 1, then the number of pais is equal to number of
    // zeroes in Y[]
    if (x == 1) return NoOfY[0];

    // Find number of elements in Y[] with values greater than x
    // upper_bound() gets address of first greater element in Y[0..n-1]
    int* idx = upper_bound(Y, Y + n, x);
    int ans = (Y + n) - idx;

    // If we have reached here, then x must be greater than 1,
    // increase number of pairs for y=0 and y=1
    ans += (NoOfY[0] + NoOfY[1]);

    // Decrease number of pairs for x=2 and (y=4 or y=3)
    if (x == 2)  ans -= (NoOfY[3] + NoOfY[4]);

    // Increase number of pairs for x=3 and y=2
    if (x == 3)  ans += NoOfY[2];

    return ans;
}

// The main function that returns count of pairs (x, y) such that
// x belongs to X[], y belongs to Y[] and x^y > y^x
int countPairs(int X[], int Y[], int m, int n)
{
    // To store counts of 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 in array Y
    int NoOfY[5] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (Y[i] < 5)
            NoOfY[Y[i]]++;

    // Sort Y[] so that we can do binary search in it
    sort(Y, Y + n);

    int total_pairs = 0; // Initialize result

    // Take every element of X and count pairs with it
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
        total_pairs += count(X[i], Y, n, NoOfY);

    return total_pairs;
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int X[] = {2, 1, 6};
    int Y[] = {1, 5};

    int m = sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0]);
    int n = sizeof(Y)/sizeof(Y[0]);

    cout << "Total pairs = " << countPairs(X, Y, m, n);

    return 0;
}
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-pairs-xy-yx/)